# How to write callback function to receive a return value from another function

Tags: node.js, express

```
app.get('/mult', function(req, res) {
    for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){
        exports.multiply(req,res);
    }
});

exports.multiply = function(req,res){

    if (req.query['valueA'] && req.query['valueB'])
        res.result = req.query['valueA'] * req.query['valueB'];
    var end = new Date() - start,
    hrend = process.hrtime(hrstart);

    console.info("Execution time: %dms", end);
    console.info("Execution time (hr): %ds %dms", hrend[0], hrend[1]/1000000);
    totalTime=totalTime+hrend[0];
    res.result=totalTime;
    console.info("Total Execution time (hr): %ds", totalTime);
    //res.send('Multiplication result: ' + res.result);
    res.send('Total execution time: ' + res.result);
};
```

I basically want to call the exports.multiply(req,res); 1000 times and store and return total execution time for all the 1000 reqest. How i can store and return the total execution time after 1000 iteration to back to the called function.

Please help in this regard!

Comment: Please format your code using these things called "spaces" or "tabs".

Comment: It doesn't seem like multiply does anything asynchronous. Can't you just `return` it the old fashion way, without a callback ?

Comment: @ploutch I am a complete new bee to node.js. I am not sure how to make this asynchronous. I am using a for loop to call the function 1000 times. I have to follow the same step for addition and subtraction and collect average execution time for each of the operation.